# Palindrome Checker Java boolean insight

Tags: java, string, boolean, palindrome

So I'm making a palindrome checker in java, and i've seemed to hit a roadblock this is my code so far:

```
public class StringUtil
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to String Util.");       
    Scanner word = new Scanner(System.in);

    String X = word.nextLine();       
    String R = palindrome(X);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Original Word: " + X);     
    System.out.println("Palindrome: " + R);



}


public static boolean palindrome(String word)
{
   int t = word.length(); //length of the word as a number
   int r = 0;


   if(word.charAt(t) == word.charAt(r))
   {
       return true;
    }
    else
    return false;
}
```

so far I only want it to check if the first letter is the same as the last, but when i compile it i get an incompatible types error on "String R = palindrome(X);" How would i get it to print true or false on the output statement below it?

Comment: Took the liberty to play around with it., http://ideone.com/oP8oxV

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `palindrome` method returns a `boolean`, but you're attempting to assign it to a `String`.  Change the definition of the `R` variable to `boolean`.

Comment: thank you. I still get confused cause i'm new at this. I'll keep that in mind for future use, it worked, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Since the characters are 0-indexed in a string (or array) in java, the last character is at length - 1

try

```
int t = word.length() - 1;
```

---

Oops, that's not the problem you're having. However, you would notice it immediately once the type error is resolved.

Comment: I noticed this also, though before I saw this. Thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Answer (score 1):

word.charAt(t - 1), otherwise you over counted the string, also return "true"; and return "false" if you'd like to use String as your result type;

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
        String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
        String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
}
```